# How to toggle between a virtual and nonvirtual block in Simulink?

Tags: virtual, simulink

In `Simulink library browser` - `Subsystem examples` - `Virtual and nonvirtual subsystem overview`, the difference between a virtual subsystem and nonvirtual subsystem is explained:

[image]

My question is how you can toggle between a virtual and nonvirtual block. I guess it is simple, but I cannot find it. Or do I understand it wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it manually,

1. Right-click on the subsystem
2. Select **Block Parameters (Subsytem)**
3. Check the 'Treat as Atomic Unit' selection box

To do it from within code, assuming that the block has been selected,

```
set_param(gcb,'TreatAsAtomicUnit','on'); % turns it on
set_param(gcb,'TreatAsAtomicUnit','off'); % turns it off
```